# Creating new dataframe with just ids columns from several existing dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I have longitudinal data and essentially I am trying to see which ids have we seen at all time points (3, 6 and 12 months). The "antenatal" ids is the list of all the enrolled participants.
I thought I would combine all of the subject ids from the different timepoints then in each row count how many times they occur, if 4 times (antenatal, 3, 6, 12 months) then we have seen them at each time point, and so on. But I am struggling to join all subject id's since there isn't a common column.

data:

```
antenatal_pids <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", 
"191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-1945", "191-2834","191-1930","191-2890","191-1232", "191-8326", "191-3000")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

df_3m <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987","191-8326", "191-1245", "191-1945", "191-3000", "191-1930"), 
edta_code = c("EDTA45", "EDTA79", "EDTA20", "EDTA66", "EDTA12", "EDTA74", "EDTA01", "EDTA05"), 
ipv = c("0", "3", "2", "2", "1", "2", "0", "4", "1")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L)) 

df_6m <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-1945", "191-3000", "191-2834", "191-2890", "191-1232"), 
edta_code = c("EDTA45", "EDTA79", "EDTA20", "EDTA66", "EDTA12", "EDTA74", "EDTA01","EDTA02","EDTA02"), 
epds = c("1", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "5", "2", "3", "5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df_12 <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-1945", "191-3000", "191-1930"), 
edta_code = c("EDTA45", "EDTA79", "EDTA20", "EDTA66", "EDTA12", "EDTA74", "EDTA01"), 
epds = c("1", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "5", "2","1","2")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

what I have tried

```
ids_3m <- df_3m %>% select(subject_id) %>% 
  rename ("subject_id_3m" = "subject_id")

ids_6m <- df_6m %>% select(subject_id) %>% 
  rename ("subject_id_6m" = "subject_id")

ids_12m <- df_12m %>% select(subject_id) %>%
rename ("subject_id_12m" = "subject_id")

all_ids <- full_join(antenatal_pids, ids_3m, ids_6m, ids_12m)
```

This of course gives an error of course

```
Error in `full_join()`:
! `by` must be a (named) character vector, list, `join_by()` result, or NULL, not a
  <tbl_df/tbl/data.frame> object.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::full_join(antenatal_pids, ids_3m, ids_6m, ids_12m)
 2. dplyr:::full_join.data.frame(antenatal_pids, ids_3m, ids_6m, ids_12m)
```

Desired output:

[image]

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to do the renaming within a `full_join()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
antenatal_pids |> 
  full_join(select(df_3m, subject_id),
            by = "subject_id",
            keep = TRUE,
            suffix = c("", "_3m")) %>% 
  full_join(select(df_6m, subject_id),
            by = "subject_id",
            keep = TRUE,
            suffix = c("", "_6m")) %>% 
  full_join(select(df_12, subject_id),
            by = "subject_id",
            keep = TRUE,
            suffix = c("", "_12")) %>% 
  mutate(no_of_visits = rowSums(!is.na(.)))
```

which gives:

```r
   subject_id subject_id_3m subject_id_6m subject_id_12 no_of_visits
1    191-5467      191-5467      191-5467      191-5467            4
2    191-6784      191-6784      191-6784      191-6784            4
3    191-3457      191-3457      191-3457      191-3457            4
4    191-0987      191-0987      191-0987      191-0987            4
5    191-1245      191-1245      191-1245      191-1245            4
6    191-1945      191-1945      191-1945      191-1945            4
7    191-2834          <NA>      191-2834          <NA>            2
8    191-1930      191-1930          <NA>      191-1930            3
9    191-2890          <NA>      191-2890          <NA>            2
10   191-1232          <NA>      191-1232          <NA>            2
11   191-8326      191-8326          <NA>          <NA>            2
12   191-3000      191-3000      191-3000      191-3000            4
``
```